# Can I animate a figure with already made bones

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

In Blender, I recently downloaded a model from UnionAvatars.com and when I added it into Blender. I saw that there was a rig inside of the character already. But I couldn't move the character. I tried to go to the **green stickfigure icon** and then go to **rigify**. but I couldnt generate the rig of that character. I really need help to know how I can move that union characters body so that I could animate it.

Comment: It's quite likely that the armature layout, bone naming, etc. don't comply with what Rigify expects as it isn't a Blender armature. Without seeing the Blend file with the model it's impossible to say what needs to be done to rig it in Blender. If it's non-commercial and smaller than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Hello, N. Barrett, welcome to BSE.  As @JohnEason suggests,  without more detail, it's not really possible to answer this, and your post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'. Please try to give us a bit more.. a share would be ideal.